# style applied from javascript does not override style from the css

Tags: javascript, css

I have style defined in css -

```
#name {
    display:none;
}
```

In JavaScript I change the style -

```
var uiElement = document.getElementById('name');
uiElement.display = "block";
```

style applied from JavaScript does not override style from the css Why?

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle with a complete code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't actually changing the `style` property. Use:

```
var uiElement = document.getElementById('name');
uiElement.style.display = "block";
// Note -^
```

Also, make sure this code is being run **after** the element is rendered/ready; otherwise, the element won't be found, and an error will be thrown anyways.

Comment: **+1** for adding a comment `^` inside the `.style` `;)`.

Answer (score 2):

you may try like this and you forgot `style` word

```
{
    document.getElementById('name').style.display = 'block';
}
```